# "Join Attributes by location (summary)" only with more than 50% of overlapping area

Tags: qgis, polygon, spatial-join, overlapping-features

I have been using the `"Join attributes by location (summary)"` tool in QGIS to help create heatmaps. I am wondering if there is a way to only join a feature if it overlaps more than 50% inside the respective area. For example, the picture below:

Orange represents a count of 1 and red a count of 0. I would prefer that only the bottom polygon is orange because it contains the majority of the green feature.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: An idea for a workaround, at least for regular shaped polygons: create the centroid of the polygon and use this to join: centroid ($geometry). In most cases the centroid will be in the part where the majority of the polygon lies. Just a heuristc approximation, however. There are for sure better solutions.

Comment: Want to make sure I am understanding you correct. Are you saying that my green polygon will most likely lie somewhere on a polygons centroid? If this is true, I don't think it will work because my green features here are pretty small compared to the polygons. I would bank that most would not touch the centroid.

Comment: No: create the centroid of the green polygon. This centroid normally should lie on the polygon (orange) that should get the attributes, right?

Comment: @babel yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS I can suggest using a **Virtual Layer** through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume we have two polygon layers `"LayerA"` (red dashed with black outline) and `"LayerB"` (light blue) respectively with its' corresponding attribute tables, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to achieve the result, i.e. to only join a feature if it overlaps more than 30% inside the respective area.

```sql
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) AS info
FROM "LayerA" AS a
JOIN "LayerB" AS b ON st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
WHERE (st_area(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry))/st_area(a.geometry))*100 > 30
GROUP BY a.id
```

The output Virtual Layer will look like as following

[image: result1]

To include a count for that polygon, please adjust the query accordingly

```sql
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) AS info, COUNT(b.geometry) As num_feat
FROM "LayerA" AS a
JOIN "LayerB" AS b ON st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
WHERE (st_area(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry))/st_area(a.geometry))*100 > 30
GROUP BY a.id
```

The output Virtual Layer will be the following

[image: result2]

---

**References:**

- [Docs » QGIS User Guide » 13.2.5. Creating virtual layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers)
- [SQLite GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/)

Comment: I understand your logic here, but how do I include a count for that polygon? Such as lets say you had four LayerA's where all were >50% within group 7. Then output 4 (as the count).

Comment: I'll give that  look today!